# Image.getScaledInstance() doesn't work

Tags: java

I would like scale image. I am trying use getScaledInstance() method by doesn't work for me. Image which I write is the same size as the funniest...

It is my code:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(file.getInputStream());
            image.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            BufferedImage bImage = (BufferedImage) image;
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", new File(urlImage));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.getScaledInstance()` **returns** an instance of the same image, scaled to the desired size **without** modifying your existing image. Assuming you are trying to save the scaled instance to file, you merely need to move the call to the line below.

E.g:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(file.getInputStream());

BufferedImage bImage = (BufferedImage) image.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", new File(urlImage));
```